# Mackey Obstruction

Tags: rt.representation-theory

What is a Mackey Obstruction?

Comment: Hello, you are more likely to get an answer if you expand your question a little.  What do you already know?  What has led you to wanting to know about Mackey Obstructions?


Comment: Google is your friend, perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

I think, it  is the obstruction of extending a projective representation of a group to a linear one  considered as an element of some H^2 cohomology group. This is quite standard and classical. You may find the definition in e.g. :

Curtis, Charles W.; Reiner, Irving Representation theory of finite groups and associative algebras. Reprint of the 1962 original. AMS Chelsea Publishing, Providence, RI, 2006.

Curtis, Charles W.; Reiner, Irving Methods of representation theory. Vol. I. With applications to finite groups and orders. Reprint of the 1981 original. Wiley Classics Library. A Wiley-Interscience Publication. John Wiley & Sons, Inc., New York, 1990. xxiv+819 pp. ISBN: 0-471-52367-4, 20-02

Answer (score 2):

For a succinct answer, read a bit of Section 2 of [this paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1994-346-02/S0002-9947-1994-1276935-9/S0002-9947-1994-1276935-9.pdf).

Also, there is a survey (the article by Judith Packer) of projective representations and the Mackey obstruction. "Projective representations and the Mackey obstruction - a survey", Contemporary Mathematics, v. 449 (2008), pp. 345-378.

(I posted this same reference as an answer to [another question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/60197/classifying-representation-through-extensions) this morning, and am surprised that both of these questions weren't asked by the same person. You two should get together and talk...)